# Ramda: mergeDeepRight + mergeAll (...perhaps mergeDeepRightAll)

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Currently in Ramda if I want to deep merge (right) multiple objects I....

```
var a = _.mergeDeepRight( { one: 1 }, { two: { three: 3 } } )
var b = _.mergeDeepRight( a, { three: { four: 4 } } )
var c = _.mergeDeepRight( b, { four: { five: 5 } } )

// c === { one:1, two: { three: 3 }, three: { four: 4 }, four: { five: 5 } }
```

If I use `_.mergeAll` (i.e. `_.mergeAll( a, b, c )`) it returns `{ one:1, two: { three:3 } }` as `_.mergeAll` is not deep

Is there a more tidy way of deep merging (right) multiple objects? Something like...

```
_.mergeDeepRightAll( a, b, c )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`reduce` might be a good call here, as we're transforming a series of items into one.

If we change the input to

```
var a = mergeDeepRight( { one: 1 }, { two: { three: 3 } } )
var b = { three: { four: 4 } }
var c = { four: { five: 5 } }
```

We can do

```
const mergeDeepAll = reduce(mergeDeepRight, {})

mergeDeepAll([a, b, c])

// -> {"four": {"five": 5}, "one": 1, "three": {"four": 4}, "two": {"three": 3}}
```

And if you wanted to provide the arguments not as an array, you can `unapply` it, although an array is more in-line with `R.mergeAll`'s signature

```
const mergeDeepAll = unapply(reduce(mergeDeepRight, {}))

mergeDeepAll(a, b, c)
```

I'll note that the examples don't actually have any conflicting keys, so a straight up `R.mergeAll` would work here. Neither of these output in the exact order you mentioned however.

Comment: About the output order: object property order is only guaranteed ES 2015+. OP should be wary of relying on it anyway.

Comment: Note that the key order change is mostly due to some output format (say `console.log` or `JSON.stringify`.)  Yes, were no guarantees before es6, but the engines have long been mostly consistent.  So `keys(mergeDeepAll([a, b, c])); //=> ["one", "two", "three", "four"]`.